# Result of the chaining of comparison operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused on how does the != operator works in python. I am new to python programming.

I know simple `!=` simply checks whether the LHS expression and RHS expression are not equal.

for eg:

```
True != False
```

returns `True`.

My question is how it works in series of `!=` operators.

e.g.: when I type

```
-5 != False != True != True
```

in my python interactive session it returns `False`, but if I solve it step by step I get the answer `True`.

Solving it step by step:

`-5 != False` returns True

`True != True` returns False

`False != True` returns True

So it should return `True` but it returns `False`. I don't know why.

Comment: There may be more exact duplicates, but the quote from the documentation in the accepted answer for this duplicate does explain what is happening.

Comment: Your last operation that is carried out is 'True != True', which is false. -5 is being compared to False. False it being compared to True. But the second to last True is being compared to True. True != True is False.

Comment: Read operation chaining here - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: Using parenthesis helps you control the order of evaluation and brings more clarity to the developer's intent. 
((-5 != False) != True) != True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, this comparation is equivalent to:

```
-5 != False and False != True and True != True
```

I.e.,

```
result = (-5 != False) and (False != True) and (True != True)
result =    (True)     and     (True)      and     (False)
result = False
```

See more in:https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons.