# Pandas date and text condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Given a df:

```
Date1                   Text1    
2018-03-20 00:00:00     abc       
2018-04-01 00:00:00     abc
2018-01-01 00:00:00     abc
2018-04-01 00:00:00     xyz
                        abc
```

My goal to add a new column where: 
if text = "abc" and Date1 is with 90 days from now then "New"
The output would be:

```
Date1                   Text1    NewText
2018-03-20 00:00:00     abc      New
2018-04-01 00:00:00     abc      New
2018-01-01 00:00:00     abc
2018-04-01 00:00:00     xyz
                        abc
```

This is what I have:

```
days90 = date.today() - timedelta(90)

df['NewText'] = np.where(df['Text1'] = "abc" & df['Date1'] < pd.to_datetime(days90), "New", np.nan)
```

However, I'm keep running into errors.
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Any suggestion? Many thanks!

Comment: `= "abc"` should be `== "abc"`

Comment: @OhadEytan Thanks! The error is still the same though :(

Comment: Suggestion to try: 'df['NewText'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['Text1'] == "abc", df['Date1'] < pd.to_datetime(days90)), "New", np.nan)'

Comment: df['NewText'] = np.where((df['Text1'] =="abc" )& ((pd.to_datetime('today')
-df['Date1'] ).dt.days< 90), "New", np.nan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 errors in your code:

1. Test equality of variables via [`==` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570371/when-to-use-and-when-to-use-is).
2. Make sure you bracket individual conditions to [avoid chained comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664057/chaining-of-comparison-operators-in-python).
3. For a date to be *within* 90 days, check your test data is *greater than* `days90`.

Combined, the following code will work:

```
df['NewText'] = np.where((df['Text1'] == "abc") & (df['Date1'] > days90), "New", np.nan)
```